# Python: Getting double directories

Tags: python, recursion

Every time my code finds a directory, it creates the folder and then creates it again within that folder, then copies the files. I'm not sure why that's happening (or more specifically, I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm sure it has everything to do with how I'm creating the destination directory paths).

Here is my copy function:

```
def dir_copy(srcpath, dstpath,):
    dstpath = os.path.join(dstpath, os.path.basename(srcpath))
    if not os.path.exists(dstpath):
            os.makedirs(dstpath)
    #tag each file to the source path to create the file path
    for file in os.listdir(srcpath):
        srcfile = os.path.join(srcpath, file)
        dstfile = os.path.join(dstpath, file)
        #if the source file path is a directory, copy the directory
        if os.path.isdir(srcfile):
            try:
                dir_copy(srcfile, dstfile)
            except:
                pass
        else: #if the source file path is just a file, copy the file
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(srcfile, dstfile)
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because of your recursive calls to dir_copy. I replaced dstfile with dstpath

```
def dir_copy(srcpath, dstpath):
    import os, shutil
    dstpath = os.path.join(dstpath, os.path.basename(srcpath))
    print dstpath
    if not os.path.exists(dstpath):
            print("dst path: %s" % dstpath)
            os.makedirs(dstpath)
    #tag each file to the source path to create the file path
    for file in os.listdir(srcpath):
        srcfile = os.path.join(srcpath, file)
        dstfile = os.path.join(dstpath, file)
        #if the source file path is a directory, copy the directory
        if os.path.isdir(srcfile):
            try:
                # modified the recursive call
                dir_copy(srcfile, dstpath)
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                pass
        else: #if the source file path is just a file, copy the file
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(srcfile, dstfile)
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                pass
```

As a side note, it's a bad habit to silently eat exceptions like that as it will make finding the source of a problem very difficult with more complex applications.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes much more sense. The only reason I'm blindly passing exceptions is because I was getting caught up in some access issues with files that shouldn't have even been copying. I'm planning on at least writing those to some sort of log file, but more than likely I'll be a little more specific about what to do there.

Comment: hope that solved it. (feel free to accept the answer if it did ;)    )

Comment: It worked for everything except the top-most level. It might be something earlier in my code. I'm trying to copy Documents, Pictures, and Desktop folders, and those are ending up doubling up once before copying. Is there anything in my code above that would cause that?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd simply like to copy src directory recursively to dest

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
src = "pathToSrc"
dst = "pathToDst"
copy_tree(src, dst)
```